# Divide 32-bit by 16-bit number on a dsPIC

Tags: microcontroller, compiler

I'm working with a `dsPIC33EP64GS506`, and here you can find its datasheet: [link](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70005127c.pdf).

In the dsPIC datasheet (page 294) it says that it supports 4 divide instructions:

```
DIV.S    Wm,Wn    Signed 16/16-bit integer divide
DIV.SD   Wm,Wn    Signed 32/16-bit integer divide
DIV.U    Wm,Wn    Unsigned 16/16-bit integer divide
DIV.UD   Wm,Wn    Unsigned 32/16-bit integer divide
```

Now, when I try to divide two variables in C, a 32-bit by a 16-bit variable, compiler for some reason decides not to use these instructions, but the `___divsi3` function instead, which is a software implementation of the divide algorithm. I use Microchip's free xc16 compiler version. Take this simple C code for example:

```
volatile int32_t num = 65537;
volatile int16_t den = 16384;
volatile int16_t res = num/den;
```

compiles to the following assembly code:

```
MOV [W15-22], W0
MOV [W15-20], W1
MOV [W15-18], W2
ASR W2, #15, W3
RCALL ___divsi3
MOV W0, [W15-16]
```

How can I convince a compiler to use `DIV.SD` instruction to divide these two variables?

Comment: What optimisation level is set for the compiler?

Comment: Does the compiler know it's got a dsPIC to play with, and that it has your permission (resource flags) to use the goodies? I'm not suggesting that inlining assembly code is a production solution, but when you do that as a test, does the PIC produce the right answers? As ever, RTFM, it must be in there somewhere. A more specific forum may be better, I would imagine PIC has its own dedicated Q/A forum?

Comment: @Neil_UK Yes, the compiler (`xc16`) is notified about the dsPIC it deals with. I've already asked on a Microchip's forum :) I managed to find a solution in the meanwhile.

Comment: @RogerRowland I tried with different optimization levels, it always uses the `___divsi3` function. As I've already explained in my second post, this problem can be fixed by using a compiler-specific (built-in) functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find a solution. Apparently, there is a dozen of `__bultin` functions used to force the compiler (`xc16`) to use specific assembly instructions or series of instructions. For example, to force the compiler to use specific `DIV` instructions, one can use one of the following `__builtin` functions:

```
signed int __builtin_divf(signed int num, signed int den);
signed int __builtin_divmodsd(signed long dividend, signed int divisor, signed int *remainder);
unsigned int __builtin_divmodud(unsigned long dividend, unsigned int divisor, unsigned int *remainder);
int __builtin_divsd(const long num, const int den);
unsigned int __builtin_divud(const unsigned long num, const unsigned int den);
```

However, one must be certain that the result (i.e., the quotient) fits to a 16-bit register, otherwise, results are unexpected. All these `builtin_div` functions execute within 18 clock cycles, while `___divsi3` function which compiler normally uses for 32/16-bit division takes up to 500 clock cycles.

To go back to my example from the beginning, the C code would look like this:

```
volatile int32_t num = 65537;
volatile int16_t den = 16384;
volatile int16_t res = __builtin_divsd(num, den);
```

The compiler produces the following assembly code:

```
MOV [W15-16], W0
MOV [W15-20], W1
MOV [W15-18], W2
REPEAT #0x11
DIV.SD W4, W2
MOV W0, [W15-14]
```

Case closed.

Comment: *"Apparently, there is a dozen of __bultin functions"* -- yes, reading the manual helps, :) the same is true with the pic32 compilers (c32 / x32).